# Facebook Api: Like a post on page as user or page

Tags: php, facebook-like

I am using PHP SDK to request an api to like a post that is on my own page.

```
$like = $facebook->api("/".$postid."/likes", 'post');
```

Yet, the code runs smoothly but when I like a post on my own page, the "like" is being sent as from the page itself, not as my user account. As of "{My Page} likes this." instead of "You like this."

Is there any workaround or maybe fields?

Permissions: (extended) publish_stream only

Update:
Facebook decided it is not necessary to fix this bug.
20/12/2012 23:06 · Status changed to Closed · Priority changed to None

Comment: It seems to be a bug within Facebook. Someone submitted the bug report on 20 Nov 2012. http://laz.im/KRHzN

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API uses the current logged in user when making API calls. So, if in your Facebook account you specified that you will use it as YOUR_PAGE_NAME then yes, all actions ex: "like", "comment", "share" etc. will be made from your page and not from your personal account. If you want to "like" posts, as of your personal account, then you should go to facebook.com, click the arrow next to "Home" menu and choose "Use Facebook as: YOUR NAME".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. Yet I am using Facebook as myself, and I also changed those activities to be made through my personal account within the page "You are posting, commenting and liking as {name}" at the top of the page.